# How to add a single custom route in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have a 'transaction' model, controller and view, which I created with rails generate. Now I need to add a single custom route of /transactions/history to my application to be handled by a controller def history:... end and render history.html.erb 
So added this line in my routes.rb:

```
get '/transactions/history', to: 'transactions#history', as: 'transactions_history'
```

And this in my transactions_controller.rb:

```
def history
    @transactions = Transaction.all
end
```

and created a history.htmk.erb in transactions->views

I also see this line when calling rake routes:

```
transactions_history GET    /transactions/history(.:format)                 transactions#history
```

But when I request localhost:3000/transactions/history in my browser, it gives me the following error:

```
Couldn't find Transaction with 'id'=history
```

(Because I have this line in my controller)

```
before_action :set_transaction, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy])
```

and I also see this line in logs:

```
Request info

Request parameters  
{"controller"=>"transactions", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"history"}
```

My full routes:
[routes.rb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E5bj.png)
My full errors:
[error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPxUW.png)
Why it is calling the 'show' action in my transaction controller?

Comment: Can you post your full routes.rb file? And a full transcript of what you see when you rake routes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `routes.rb`, the rails scaffold generator should have added a `resources :transactions`. This will generate 7 routes for you, one of them being `/transactions/:id` which corresponds to the show action in `TransactionsController`.

Rails matches the routes in the order defined in `routes.rb` and will call the controller action of the **first** matching route.

I am guessing in your case you defined `get '/transactions/history', to: 'transactions#history', as: 'transactions_history'` below `resources :transactions`. As you are passing `/transactions/history`, this is calling the `show` action with the `:id` matching `history`.

To fix this, there are 2 solutions:

First, move your custom route above the `resources :transactions`.

Or extend the `resources` declaration and remove your custom route like so:

```
resources :transactions do
  collection do
    get :history
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried your second solution and did not worked (same error)

Comment: You should only have one `resources :transactions`. Post your `routes.rb`

Comment: That solved the problem, I did not know that point of having only one resources :transaction.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It is because your route is conflicting with the default resource route, specifically `GET transactions/:id`.

```
resources :transactions do
  get :history, on: :collection
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes

You can also try:

1. Switching the order that your routes are defined, or
2. Changing your custom route so it does not conflict, e.g. instead of `/transactions/history` try `/transaction_history` or something else.

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: Yes, I have restarted that